# Data table escape regex - dropdown list filter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Working on someone else's project. .Net Core MVC Web Application. On the User Administration page (View), we use data tables to have filters on each of the columns such as date, a-z, z-a, dropdown filters etc. They all seem to be working except for the drop-down filters.

The HTML mark-up for said dropdown list is:

```
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="<span>Just A User</span>">Just A User</option>
  <option value="<span>ABC Admin</span>">ABC Admin</option>
  <option value="<span>Primary Admin - Primary</span>">Primary Admin - Primary</option>
</select>
```

The Datatables section of code that handles this search (columns 1 and 7 are the dropdown list filter columns)

```
this.api().columns([1,7]).every(function (index) {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) td').eq(this.index()))
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                                
                            );
                            console.log(val);                            
                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                    });
                });
```

I have put a breakpoint on the `var` declaration with the `.on('change')` function. I have noticed that the value of val contains the html of the element, with some extra characters:

```
 <span>Primary Admin \- Primary<\/span>
 <span>Just A User<\/span>
 <span>ABC Admin<\/span>
```

I think what is happened is the code is searching for the above text (depending on what dropdown value is selected) and is not finding any results due to either the invalid HTML or the fact that there is HTML within the string (i.e search for `ABC Admin` and not for `<span>ABC Admin<\/span>` )

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit: Razor code that generates one of said dropdown lists: (this is within a foreach loop that iterates over every user)

```
<td>
                    @{
                        switch (item.AccountType)
                        {
                            case "OPT":
                                <span>Just A User</span>
                                break;        
                            case "RSS":
                                <span>ABC Admin</span>
                                break;
                            case "RA1":
                                 <span>Primary - Primary</span>
                                break;
                        }
                    }
</td>
```

Comment: So why are these HTML tags part of those option values to begin with, why are they not just the plain text?

Comment: They are coming from the Razor code that generates the html. Let me edit my original post to include this,

Comment: Sounds like something I'd rather try and fix in that templating code then; but you can also try and just strip any HTML tags from the value inside your change handler, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Or strip it in the place where you create the options already. (I.e., strip that first `d` in `select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');` from any extra tags.

Comment: Thank you let me give that a go and I'll get back to you.

Comment: No luck with trying to modify the value within the on change, textContent (and also innerHTML just equates to an undefined value)

https://imgur.com/a/TuP44kW

I'm not sure entirely what you mean about your other method, stripping the first 'd'

Comment: `$(this).val()` gets you a string here, and that doesn't have a `textContent` property. You would either need to create a temporary HTML element first (accepted answer in the mentioned discussion), or use a regex replace like in the one below that.